# Go interface with String() method

Tags: string, go, tostring

Is there a Go interface in the standard library with:

```
String() string
```

?

(Similar to how Java has toString() on java.lang.Object)

Perhaps I just didn't search enough but I didn't see one.  Wanted to use one that already exists rather than than making my own (though I guess it really makes no difference with Go's type system).

Comment: You could use the [`implements`](https://github.com/dominikh/implements) tool to answer questions of this form. In this case, you'd find any package that has structs with `String()` methods, say, `time`, which has quite a few, and then run `implements -types time`, and look at the interfaces it says are implemented by the various `time` types.

Comment: Nice - just tried it.  Works well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`fmt.Stringer`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) is what you're after.

```
type Stringer interface {
        String() string
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I've seen to Java's `toString` is [fmt#Stringer](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer).